# How to define an internal link as parent in mymodule.links.menu.yml?

Tags: 8, navigation

How do I create a menu link programmatically to a node that I can use as a parent for other links?

In `MYMODULE.links.module`, I defined some links for my navbar:

```
MYMODULE.parent-fruits:
  title: 'Fruits'
  url: internal:/fruits
  weight: 0
  menu_name: food
MYMODULE.fruits-apple:
  title: 'Apple'
  parent: MYMODULE.parent-fruits
  route_name: view.fruits.apple
  weight: 5
  menu_name: food
MYMODULE.parent-vegetables:
  route_name: view.vegetables.page-main
  weight: 10
  menu_name: food
MYMODULE.vegetables-asparagus:
  parent: MYMODULE.parent-vegetables
  title: 'Asparagus'
  url: internal:/admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/card_group_private/add
  weight: 5
  menu_name: food
```

In this case, I expect to have a menu that looks like this:

- Fruits (child-> Apple)
- Vegetables (child-> asparagus)

When I go to the parent page, the link to the child should appear in the navbar menu (the parent tree should be expanded).

But what I actually get is:

- Fruits (**no children**)
- Vegetables (child-> asparagus)

The problem is caused by defining the menu link with `url` instead of `route_name`.  I know this because when I change the parent of `fruits-apple` to `parent: MYMODULE.parent-vegetables`, then I see `Apple` as a child of `Vegetables`.

When I remove `parent` from `Apple`, then it appears in the menu (without a parent), so I know the link is defined correctly.

I can also create the `Fruits` / `Apple` links in the menu UI, and those work correctly.

Regarding `parent:` the [documentation says this:](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links)

> Determining the parent menu_link name can be a little tricky at first.
> If you know the path of the parent menu item, you would need to search
> for it in all available *.routing.yml files (most text editors and
> IDEs should allow you to search all files in a project) and find the
> route name for that path. Then, you would need to search for the route
> name in all available *.links.menu.yml files. The menu_link whose
> route_name matches is your link. Alternatively, if you know which
> module is defining the parent menu link (or one of the parent menu
> link's children), you can go straight to that module and perform your
> search.

Since these are node links, I checked `node.routing.yml` in the core node module, but I couldn't find the route to node pages.

So: how do I create a menu link programmatically to a node that I can use as a parent for other links?

Comment: I think changing from `url` to `route_name` is *the* solution, you normally use `url` only for external links.

Comment: @4k4 Ok, how do I get the route name for something like `/node/7`?  I updated my question with the explanation I found in the docs, which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing from `url` to `route_name` is *the* solution, you normally use `url` only for external links.

You don't find entity routes in static yml files because they are created dynamically. You could use the Devel module and visit

```
/devel/routes
```

or from the command line with Drupal Console:

```
drupal debug:router
```

See https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/commands/debug-router

Then when you have found the route name you have to add the entity id as route parameter.

Example:

*mymodule.links.menu.yml*

```
mymodule.node7:
  title: 'Node 7'
  route_name: 'entity.node.canonical'
  route_parameters: { node: '7' }
```